# How to set default value of tkinter checkboxtreeview to "checked"

Tags: tkinter, checkbox, treeview, default-value, ttkwidgets

I created a checkbox treeview with ttkwidgets. I want these checkboxes to be "checked" by default. How can I do that.

```Python
from tkinter import *
from ttkwidgets import CheckboxTreeview
import tkinter as tk
    
root = tk.Tk()
    
tree = CheckboxTreeview(root)
tree.pack()
    
list = [("apple"), ("banana"), ("orange")]
    
n=0
for x in list:
    tree.insert(parent="", index="end", iid=n,  text=x)
    n+=1
    
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking into the `ttkwidgets` source code for the `CheckboxTreeview` widget [here](https://github.com/TkinterEP/ttkwidgets/blob/master/ttkwidgets/checkboxtreeview.py), I found this `change_state` method

```Python
def change_state(self, item, state):
    """
    Replace the current state of the item.
    i.e. replace the current state tag but keeps the other tags.
        
    :param item: item id
    :type item: str
    :param state: "checked", "unchecked" or "tristate": new state of the item 
    :type state: str
    """
    tags = self.item(item, "tags")
    states = ("checked", "unchecked", "tristate")
    new_tags = [t for t in tags if t not in states]
    new_tags.append(state)
    self.item(item, tags=tuple(new_tags))
```

It seems like this is the intended way to set the check state for your treeview items, so you should be able to do this

```
tree.change_state(iid, 'checked')  # where 'iid' is the item id you want to modify
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the source code for `CheckboxTreeview`, you can set `tags=("checked",)` to make the checkbox *checked* initially when calling `.insert(...)`:

```py
list = ["apple", "banana", "orange"]

for n, x in enumerate(list):
    tree.insert(parent="", index="end", iid=n,  text=x, tags=("checked",))
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want these checkboxes to be "checked" by default.

The problem can be fixed.

On line 14, add `tags=`

```
tree.insert(parent="", index="end", iid=n,  text=x, tags=("checked",) <==add tags=(
```

Screenshot:

[image]